# how can apply the circle criterion?

Tags: functions, laplace-transform, nonlinear-system

My question is:
If I have a transfer function $(G(s)=\frac{2}{(s+1)^2})$ like the one in picture , and I want to determinate the lower value on the real axis of the function in the nyquist diagram, in order to apply the circle criterion, how can I do?
with the matlab plot I found that this point is near the value $\frac{-1}{4}$ but how can I found this value in an analitical way?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please name your axis so that they match the equation.

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity. using the circle criterion, in order to prove the stability of my nonlinear system, i need to be able to guarantee that the nyquist diagram of the traasfer function does not intersect the circle touching the real axis at the points -1/k2 and -1/k1, with k1 and k2 being the slopes of the straight lines where my sector function lives. so in order to understand this i need to be able to calculate the extreme (negative) value of the function G(jw) on the real axis of the nyquist diagram. the picture I have included describes my function but only qualitatively.

Comment: i know that it intersects the real axis at the value of static gain 2, on the positive half-plane and that for w->inf the diagram will converge to 0. however, my goal is to be able to calculate the value that the real part of the function takes at the leftmost possible point.  (the dashed line in the picture).